# PHP Array next items as children

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have a project with a list of filters having some given options. Each option should contain the next parent's children. So basically the entire array must be parsed from the end to the beginning of it, but I am not sure how would be the best to do it in PHP.

The initial list looks like this:

```
Model
 - Paper basic
 - Paper standard
Format
 - 12x7x3 cm
 - 15x15x5 cm
Color
 - White
 - Blue
 - Red
```

Visually, what I need to do is this:

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%;">

  <tr><td>Paper basic</td><td>12x7x3 cm</td><td>White</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Red</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>15x15x5 cm</td><td>White</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Red</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Paper standard</td><td>12x7x3 cm</td><td>White</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Red</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>15x15x5 cm</td><td>White</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Red</td></tr>
</table>
```

```
PHP Array:

$parents = array();

$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = 1;
$parent['name'] = 'Model';
$parent['slug'] = 'model';
$parent['type'] = 'filter';

$parent['children'] = array();

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 1;
$child['name'] = 'Paper basic';
$child['slug'] = 'paper-basic';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 2;
$child['name'] = 'Paper standard';
$child['slug'] = 'paper-standard';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

array_push($parents, $parent);


$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = 2;
$parent['name'] = 'Format';
$parent['slug'] = 'format';
$parent['type'] = 'filter';

$parent['children'] = array();

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 3;
$child['name'] = '12x7x3 cm';
$child['slug'] = '12x7x3-cm';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 4;
$child['name'] = '15x15x5 cm';
$child['slug'] = '15x15x5-cm';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

array_push($parents, $parent);



$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = 3;
$parent['name'] = 'Color';
$parent['slug'] = 'color';
$parent['type'] = 'filter';

$parent['children'] = array();

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 5;
$child['name'] = 'White';
$child['slug'] = 'white';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 6;
$child['name'] = 'Blue';
$child['slug'] = 'blue';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = array();
$child['id'] = 7;
$child['name'] = 'Red';
$child['slug'] = 'red';
$child['type'] = 'option';
array_push($parent['children'], $child);

array_push($parents, $parent);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($parents);
echo '</pre>';
```

array result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Model
            [slug] => model
            [type] => filter
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Paper basic
                            [slug] => paper-basic
                            [type] => option
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Paper standard
                            [slug] => paper-standard
                            [type] => option
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Format
            [slug] => format
            [type] => filter
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => 12x7x3 cm
                            [slug] => 12x7x3-cm
                            [type] => option
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => 15x15x5 cm
                            [slug] => 15x15x5-cm
                            [type] => option
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Color
            [slug] => color
            [type] => filter
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => White
                            [slug] => white
                            [type] => option
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Blue
                            [slug] => blue
                            [type] => option
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [name] => Red
                            [slug] => red
                            [type] => option
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I tried something like this, but it's only working for the next items but the next items should contain the children of their next one:

```
for ($j = 0; $j <= count($parents); $j++)
   {
      if (isset($parents[$j+1]['children']))
      {
         array_push($parents[$j]['children'], $parents[$j+1]['children']);
      }
   }
```

Comment: please include the code of what you've tried so far! And the source array (best as parseable from `var_export($yourarray)`)

Comment: with the given array you basicly need 3 nested foreach-loops: one for 'model'. `$parents[0]['children']`, one for 'format `$parents[1]['children']`, one for 'Color' `$parents[2]['children']`

Comment: Problem is that there aren't only 3 foreach-loops, it can be an unlimited amount of parents. What I tried was this (see above, latest code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with a solution without the need of nested loop for all parents array. Just nested loop for cells in rows and work for as many parents as you can have. Make use of modulo to determine the content of each row.

```
$total_rows = 1;
foreach($parents as $parent)
{
    $total_rows *= count($parent["children"]);
}


$rows = '';
for($row = 0;$row < $total_rows;$row++)
{
    $cells = '';
    $count_product = 1;
    for($col = count($parents) - 1;$col >= 0;$col--)
    {
        $parent = $parents[$col];
        $cells = '<td>' . ((($row % $count_product) == 0) ? $parent["children"][($row/$count_product)%count($parent["children"])]["name"] : "") . '</td>' . $cells;
        $count_product *= count($parent["children"]);
    }
    $rows .= '<tr>'.$cells.'<tr>';
}

echo '<table>'.$rows.'</table>';
```

Comment: This one is indeed working. Thanks a lot, that's the result I wanted.

Comment: The view part is fine, problem is now that I need to add input fields for all the cells, and the only thing I have is the parent ID, column and row index. The input fields look like this: https://i.gyazo.com/12d6f48622899cb7ba641b8929703267.png  and the field items are not unique, for example color "Wit mat" belongs to "Basic > 22+10x31cm > hard geplastifi..." but also to "Basic > 26+12x37 > hard geplastifi..."

Comment: I need to save unique values in a separate table in db, but can't be "attached" by filter option ID. I used filter_option_id, row_index, column_index, but problem come when i want to add a new Formaat or Model, then the whole structure will be different (rows and column indexes).. Any idea how I could do this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some (til now ugly) code, that does what you need:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
foreach($parents[0]['children'] as $model) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$model['name']."</td>";
    $firstFormatDone=false;
    foreach($parents[1]['children'] as $format) {
        if($firstFormatDone) {
            echo "<tr><td></td>";
        }
        echo "<td>".$format['name']."</td>";
        $firstFormatDone=true;
        $firstColorDone=false;

        foreach($parents[2]['children'] as $color) {
            if($firstColorDone) {
                echo "<tr><td></td><td></td>";
            }
            echo "<td>".$color['name']."</td>";
            $firstColorDone=true;
            echo "<tr>";
        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

As you can see, there's a pattern that should be put into a recoursive function (because now you said, that the amount of hierarchies isn't fixed)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a good idea. I will have to make it in a recursive function, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do not like to have a couple of `foreaches` within each other.

Perhaps you are **looking** for this: *If it is not, please let me know.*

```
$parents = [];

$parent = [
    'id'       => 1,
    'name'     => 'Model',
    'slug'     => 'model',
    'type'     => 'filter',
    'children' => [],
];

$child = [
    'id'   => 1,
    'name' => 'Paper basic',
    'slug' => 'paper-basic',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = [
    'id'   => 2,
    'name' => 'Paper standard',
    'slug' => 'paper-standard',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);
array_push($parents, $parent);

$parent = [
    'id'       => 2,
    'name'     => 'Format',
    'slug'     => 'format',
    'type'     => 'filter',
    'children' => [],
];

$child = [
    'id'   => 3,
    'name' => '12x7x3 cm',
    'slug' => '12x7x3-cm',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = [
    'id'   => 4,
    'name' => '15x15x5 cm',
    'slug' => '15x15x5-cm',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);
array_push($parents, $parent);

$parent = [
    'id'       => 3,
    'name'     => 'Color',
    'slug'     => 'color',
    'type'     => 'filter',
    'children' => [],
];

$child = [
    'id'   => 5,
    'name' => 'White',
    'slug' => 'white',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = [
    'id'   => 6,
    'name' => 'Blue',
    'slug' => 'blue',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);

$child = [
    'id'   => 6,
    'name' => 'Red',
    'slug' => 'red',
    'type' => 'option',
];

array_push($parent['children'], $child);
array_push($parents, $parent);

foreach ($parents as $parent)
{
    foreach ($parent as $child)
    {
        if (is_array($child))
        {
            foreach ($child as $result)
            {
                echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($result);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Outcome:**

```
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "Paper basic"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(11) "paper-basic"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Paper standard"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(14) "paper-standard"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(3)
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "12x7x3 cm"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(9) "12x7x3-cm"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(4)
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "15x15x5 cm"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(10) "15x15x5-cm"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(5)
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "White"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(5) "white"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(6)
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "Blue"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(6)
  ["name"]=>
  string(3) "Red"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(3) "red"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "option"
}
```

Related to your `HTML`. You could do **this**:

```
foreach ($parents as $parent)
{
    foreach ($parent as $child)
    {
        if (is_array($child))
        {
            foreach ($child as $result): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result['name'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['slug'] ;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['type'] ;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;
        }
    }
}
```

**Documentation:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php // foreach
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php // is_array

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try and let you know.

Comment: Awesome! Perhaps the code might need to be changed somewhat. I am not sure if everything you need is inside the `$result` array. Also: you might want to create a `function` -> `class` for this.